# Find squares / rectangles from image that has overlay using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, math, object-detection

I am trying to find squares of an image based on overlays that streamers use to stream in applications like OBS, and I would like to know if someone knows a better approach than the one that I am doing.

Example of image and result of my code using cv2 and python (notice that I am not allowed to add images, so link is provided instead):

[image]

[image]

My strategy is:

- Resize and blur the image
- Find all lines in the image based on cv2.HoughLinesP
- Get common lines and then get points from them
- Try to find possible squares / rectangles from points

I'm trying to find all squares/rectangles and then retrieve only the big one, but I'm not having good results. Does someone know any library or strategy that could I use to get biggest square/rectangle from image that has an overlay.

Comment: Very interesting question! However, could you please explain what you mean by *"but I'm not having good results"*? What kind of results do you have? Why are they not good enough? Could you show the actual implementation of your strategy?

Comment: I would like to have squares / rectangles that are human visible, or at least the biggest one. In the second image that is attached in (result of my code) you can see what I output after finding them. I will try to upload the code to github and share it here, because there are several files involved!